# Android SIP Client SipManager.open() is not opening

Tags: android, sip, voip

I've been coding a SIP client using the Android SDK's native SIP libs.
For some reason I cannot get my account to register with the server.

Here are the testing grounds:

- Linux Mint 17 XFCE running a Kamailio Server(MySQL and TLS enabled).
- Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon running Android Studio (0.8.6).
- Asus Google Nexus 7 (2nd gen).
- All of the above are on 192.168.1.xxx

The server and account info has been tested with a working SipClient (ZoIPer). The port 5060 has been tested with a telnet command from the coding machine to the server. The client I'm building has also been tested with a third-party SIP service on a distant server (with identical results). Is there any idea how to make it works?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public CommsController cc;
public IncomingCallReceiver callReceiver;
public Context ctx = this;

Button callButton;
EditText phoneTextBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cc = new CommsController();
    cc.createManager(this);

    cc.createProfile("linasAndroid","192.168.1.140","android001");

    callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("util.Controller.IncomingCallReceiver");
    this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);

    cc.openProfile(this);

    try {
        System.out.println("+++ IS API SUPPORTED: " + cc.getManager().isApiSupported(this));
        System.out.println("+++ IS VOIP SUPORTED: " + cc.getManager().isVoipSupported(this));
        System.out.println("+++ MANAGER INSTANCE: " + cc.getManager().toString());
        boolean isOpened = cc.getManager().isOpened(cc.getMe().getUriString());
        System.out.println("+++ IS OPENED: "+isOpened);

        if(isOpened){
            cc.getManager().register(cc.getMe(), 30000, cc.getSrl());
            cc.createRegistrationListener();

        }

    }catch(SipException sipex){
        System.out.println(sipex.getCause()+", "+ sipex.getMessage());
        //sipex.printStackTrace();
    }

    callButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.callButton);
    phoneTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneTextBox);


    callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cc.makeCall("sip:"+phoneTextBox.getText()+"@192.168.1.140");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
}

public Context getContext(){return ctx;}

public CommsController getCc() {
    return cc;
}
```

**CommsController**

```
public class CommsController {

public String sipAddress = null;
public SipManager manager = null;
public SipProfile me = null;
public SipAudioCall call = null;
public Context ctx;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
public SipRegistrationListener srl;

private static final int CALL_ADDRESS = 1;
private static final int SET_AUTH_INFO = 2;
private static final int UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG = 3;
private static final int HANG_UP = 4;

SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener(){
    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
        call.startAudio();
        call.setSpeakerMode(true);
        call.toggleMute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
        // Do something.
    }
};

public void createManager(Context context) {
    if (manager == null) {
        manager = SipManager.newInstance(context);
    }
}


public boolean createProfile(String uname, String domain, String pass){

    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(uname, domain);
        builder.setPassword(pass);
        builder.setProtocol("TCP");
        builder.setPort(5060);
        me = builder.build();
        setMe(me);
        System.out.println("+++ User Profile = CREATED");
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("+++ User Profile = FAILED");
        return false;
    }
}

public void openProfile(Context context){
    try {
    System.out.println("+++ ATTEMPTING TO OPEN PROFILE: " + me.getUriString());

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("util.Controller.IncomingCallReceiver");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    manager.open(getMe(), pendingIntent, null);
    System.out.println("+++ IS OPEN IN CC: " +manager.isOpened(getMe().getUriString()));

    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("+++ Profile Registration = FAILED");
    }
}

public void createRegistrationListener(){
    System.out.println("+++ CREATING REG LISTENER...");

    srl = new SipRegistrationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                System.out.println("+++ REGISTERING...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                System.out.println("+++ READY");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                System.out.println("+++ REGISTRATION FAILED. CHECK SETTINGS. ERROR: "+ errorCode + " MESSAGE: " +errorMessage);
            }
    };

}

public SipRegistrationListener getSrl(){
    return srl;
}

public void closeProfile(SipProfile toClose){
    if(manager==null){
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.close(toClose.getUriString());
            System.out.println("PROFILE CLOSED: " +toClose.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("FAILED TO CLOSE LOCAL PROFILE: "+ toClose.toString());
    }

}

public void logOut(){
    try {
        System.out.println("+++ DEREGISTERING...");
        manager.close(me.getUriString());
    }catch(SipException se){
        System.out.println("+++ DEREGISTRATION FAILED");
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void makeCall(String toCall){
    try {
        call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), toCall, listener, 30);
    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Getters and setters...
```

**Output (LogCat)**

```
09-09 16:46:53.709  22783-22783/com.inlusion.inlusip I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
09-09 16:46:53.739  22783-22783/com.inlusion.inlusip D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-09 16:46:55.841  22783-22783/com.inlusion.inlusip I/System.out﹕ +++ User Profile = CREATED
09-09 16:46:55.841  22783-22783/com.inlusion.inlusip I/System.out﹕ +++ ATTEMPTING TO OPEN PROFILE: sip:linasAndroid@192.168.1.140;transport=tcp
09-09 16:46:55.921  22783-22783/com.inlusion.inlusip D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 316K, 4% free 9182K/9532K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
09-09 16:46:55.941  22783-22783/com.inlusion.inlusip I/System.out﹕ +++ IS OPEN IN CC: false
09-09 16:46:55.941  22783-22783/com.inlusion.inlusip I/System.out﹕ +++ IS API SUPPORTED: true
09-09 16:46:55.941  22783-22783/com.inlusion.inlusip I/System.out﹕ +++ IS VOIP SUPORTED: true
09-09 16:46:55.941  22783-22783/com.inlusion.inlusip I/System.out﹕ +++ MANAGER INSTANCE: android.net.sip.SipManager@4256de78
09-09 16:46:55.941  22783-22783/com.inlusion.inlusip I/System.out﹕ +++ IS OPENED: false
```

**EDIT:**

After messing around with pjsip, mjsip and jain-sip, I desparately made one last attempt to rewrite this using the SDKs sip stack, in a more structured manner, separating the methods into classes that handle talking to the registrar, handling a call etc., you know- standard MVC layout.

After two weeks of repackaging third-party libraries and trying to figure out the NDK...
This bastard worked. Goes to show - ***structure your code right!***

**EDIT 2:**

The issue is back after removing the app from the device and running it again. Once more- no idea what's causing it. Had gotten to the point where I could register, unregister and make two way audio calls until it started happening again.

**EDIT 3:**

It seems the problem goes away when the device is rebooted. Starting to think it's either an unclosed socket or a previously opened profile. Any suggestions?

**EDIT 4:**

Bug also occurs when another VoIP SIP application (with the pjsip OR mjsip stack) is present and connected to the server with the same account credentials.

Comment: Anyone? I'm even resorting to compiling tons of tools and trying out pjsip.

Comment: `manager.open(getMe(), pendingIntent, null);` instead null put `srl` then in onRegistrationDone of this listener do the check

Comment: for some reason, after rewriting everything from ground-up and restructuring, manager.open(getMe()); and attaching a listener afterwards, worked, even without the pendingIntent.