# How to add JAIN SIP?

Tags: android, sip, jain-sip

I write some code in Java on my PC using JAIN SIP 1.2, now I want to export some of my work and create new ones for Android, but I can't understand how to do it. I see another posts like [Android-ready JAIN-SIP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908817/android-ready-jain-sip-library) that redirect to a Github repo, where I can't find any documentation, or I don't know where to find it, to how to add JAIN SIP to android.

I found another ways to use JAIN SIP from older post: using two jar, adding them to my Android project: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.sip/android-jain-sip-ri/1.3.0-91 and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.sip/jain-sip-api/1.2.1.4 but I get a lot of compilation errors.

Clarify that I'm not familiar with implementing jar files in Android.

I just want to make a presence service, subscribing my phone to my computer just for receive some data, that I've already write and it's functional on my computer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post here what errors are you getting? There is a special android build you should use https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/android-jsip/ where all packages are prefixed with `android.`

There is a javadoc with the packages here https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/android-jsip/javadoc/

There is also an android example here how to use the android packages in an app

https://github.com/usnistgov/jsip/tree/master/src/examples/android/simplecallsetup

Comment: Thank you so much, with that build my code is finally working! I really thank you, I can finally finish my last project to finish my degree.